# No matching function - c++

Tags: c++, function, reference

I have the following constructor:

```
RegMatrix(int numRow, int numCol, std::vector<double> fill);
```

and inside one of my functions:

```
RegMatrix RegMatrix::operator+(RegMatrix &matrix)
```

I create:

```
std::vector<ThreeDigits> fill;
```

and then I return:

```
return RegMatrix(1,2,fill);
```

and it says I return `(int,int,std::vector<ThreeDigits>&)` ...
Why is that and how can I fix it?

Comment: What do you mean "it says I return std::vector&"?  What is the exact error message?

Comment: no matching function for call to RegMatrix::RegMatrix(int,int,std::vector<ThreeDigits>&)

Comment: Say what? `ThreeDigits` is not a `double`, is `RegMatrix` a constructor or a function?, you aren't returning 3 types, post the actual code and the compiler error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::vector<double>` is not the same type as `std::vector<ThreeDigits>`. You can fix this problem by either creating `RegMatrix::RegMatrix(int, int, const std::vector<ThreeDigits>&)`, or by modifying the declaration of `fill`: `std::vector<double> fill;`.

Comment: Unless `ThreeDigits` happens to be a typedef for `double`.

Comment: ..and even if there's an implicit conversion from `double` to `ThreeDigits`, that doesn't mean there's an implicit conversion from `vector<double>` to `vector<ThreeDigits>`.